# Coffeescript: "else" within array comprehension

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript, list-comprehension

Does coffeescript offer an equivalent for "else" within array comprehensions like python's list comprehensions?

#### Python example

```
foo = ["yes" if i < 50 else "no" for i in range(100)]
```

Since, in python, the if/else is actually a ternary statement, I figured coffeescript might be similar, so I tried this:

#### coffeescript attempt

```
foo = (if i < 50 then "yes" else "no" for i in [0..100])
```

The difference is that python appropriately gives me 50 yes's and 50 no's, but coffeescript only gives me a single "yes".

So, just to be clear, I want to know if there is a way to use an "else" in coffeescript's array comprehensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original query transpiles to this:

```
var _i, _results;
if (i < 50) {
  return "yes";
} else {
  _results = [];
  for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 100; i = ++_i) {
    _results.push("no");
  }
  return _results;
}
```

As you can see, the `i < 50` is met immediately since it's undefined, which returns a single "yes".

You need to rewrite it this way to get the desired result:

```
foo = ((if i < 50 then "yes" else "no") for i in [0..100])
```

This results in the following:

```
for (i = _i = 0; _i <= 100; i = ++_i) {
  _results.push(i < 50 ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

New lines and indention also work.  Turning a loop into a comprehension is almost too easy in Coffeescript.

```
x = for i in [0..100]
   if i<50 then 'yes' else 'no'
```